# Google Analytics report showing visits per month for a set of urls

Tags: google-analytics

I need to create an analytics report which shows the number of visits per page across a selection of months.

For example:

```
Page   | Month    | Visits
Page A | January  | 10,000
Page A | February | 12,500
Page B | January  | 5,400
Page B | February | 5,200
```

Or even:

```
Page   | January | February | ...
Page A | 10,000  | 12,500   | ...
Page B |  5,400  |  5,200   | ...
```

I've tried a number of tables in the custom dashboard but can't get anything close to this. Is it even possible to do?

Comment: Have you tried custom reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to create a custom report.   You can add a secondary dimension of "Time" → "Month of the year" to the "Behavior" → "Site Content" → "All Pages" report:

[image]

Comment: This is great. Thanks for the tip. I will still create a custom report as I have quite a few of these with various filters to wire up, but this is really useful.